# Is there a way to access the current approval step when writing an Apex trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I'm writing an Apex trigger that executes before an update, and I would like to know if it's possible to figure out the current approval step in the process.

These are some of the resources that I have found that seem related to this:

About the Process Submit Request: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ProcessSubmitRequest.htm#!

About the Process Instance Step: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstancestep.htm

About the Process Result:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ProcessResult.htm

The ProcessSubmitRequest seems like the class that is closest to what I want to do. From the looks of it, it seems like it's automatic and just moves the record up the approval pipeline but it doesn't take any parameters. I don't see anything in it that verifies the specific step it is in the approval process.

When it comes to the Process Instance Step, I only see the different responses, such as whether it is approved, rejected, pending, removed, or started, but I don't see anything about the specific step it is in the approval process, which I would expect to be a number like 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Am I looking into the wrong resources for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you done any research before posting here?

Comment: Yes, I have done some research into the topic, but a lot of the questions that I've seen on the same topic about whether the current approval step can be accessed at the API level haven't been answered or had trails of other people wanting to know the answer as well. I'm currently looking into the ProcessRequest class.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include links to what you have found and explain what you are still hung up on. As written, your post does not demonstrate any of that effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is...but it's not exactly the easiest thing in the world. As a disclaimer, I don't really have access to my org right now, so I haven't checked all of this to make sure that it all works.

A good first step is to determine whether or not your record is currently locked or not. Since around Spring '16 (API v36.0), Approval Processes have not been the only way to lock a record, but if a record is in an Approval Process, it will be locked. The [Appoval class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) contains an `isLocked(Id)` method, that tells you whether or not the record is currently locked. If the record isn't locked, then you don't need to do any more work.

After that, the two objects you'll be working with are `ProcessInstance` and `ProcessInstanceStep`.

The `ProcessInstance` object is just that, an individual instance of the Approval Process. This object contains the `TargetObjectId` field, which is populated with the Id of the record that is in the Approval Process.

The `ProcessInstanceStep` object contains the records for each individual step in your approval process. It's actually a little more complicated than that though. If you have multiple approvers for a given step, there will be one `ProcessInstanceStep` record for each approver, for each step. This object also has a foreign key (i.e. something like a lookup or master-detail relationship) back to `ProcessInstance`.

The `StepStatus` field of `ProcessInstance` is where you'll be looking at to determine which approval step is the current one. I'm not sure of when each status can be assigned, but for reference, the statuses are:

- Approved
- Fault
- Held
- NoResponse
- Pending
- Reassigned
- Rejected
- Removed
- Started

From that list, `Started` seems to be the logical choice for the step that the Approval Process is currently on. `Approved`, `Rejected`, and `NoResponse` all suggest that action has been taken. `Pending` means you haven't reached that step yet. `Removed` is self-explanitory. `Fault` and `Held`, I have no idea about. And finally, `Reassigned` may be another indicator of the current step.

So, putting all of that together, the query to fetch the current approval steps for a given record would look something like

```
[
    SELECT 
        Id, TargetObjectId, 
        (
            SELECT 
                Id, StepNodeId, StepStatus 
            FROM 
                Steps  // The relationship name for ProcessInstanceStep is 'Steps'
            WHERE 
                StepStatus IN (\'Started\')
        )
    FROM 
        ProcessInstance 
    WHERE 
        TargetObjectId = :myRecordId
]
```

You might be wondering why I included `StepNodeId` in that subquery. The reason is because while that subquery will get you the instance of the approval process step, `ProcessInstanceStep` does not tell you the name of the approval step. If your logic only takes into account the amount of time that the current approval step has been in progress, then you can stop here. I'm guessing that most people will want the name of the approval step though. For that, we need to query the `ProcessNode` and/or `ProcessInstanceNode` objects (I'm not 100% straight on the differences between all of these objects).

I believe that `ProcessInstanceStep.StepNodeId` related to `ProcessInstanceNode`, which has the `ProcessNodeName` field. Not sure if this is the developer name (which I think is, rather unintuitively, the name with whitespaces) or the unique name (the one with underscores).

`ProcessNode` contains both `DeveloperName` (again, this seems to be analagous to an SObject field's label), and the `Name` (analagous to the api name of an SObject field).

Again, another subquery can take care of you here

```
[
    SELECT 
        Id, DeveloperName, Name, 
        (
            SELECT 
                Id, ProcessNodeName 
            FROM 
                ProcessInstanceNodes 
            WHERE 
                Id IN :collectionOfStepNodeIdFromPreviousQuery
        )
    FROM 
        ProcessNode 
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT 
            ProcessNodeId 
        FROM 
            ProcessInstanceNode 
        WHERE 
            Id IN :collectionOfStepNodeIdFromPreviousQuery
    )
]
```

That should hopefully get you going. I'm not sure how you'd tie the name of an Approval Process step to the sequence number of that step in a given Approval Process (if you do end up needing that). As I'm sure you now know, when we get outside of the "normal" objects, the amount of documentation drops off of a pretty steep cliff, and it takes more time and experimentation to suss out how things work.

Comment: thank you very much for this information. I'm having problems in that I am following this process but do not seem to be getting all of the ProcessInstanceSteps for a multi step Approval Process. I first do a query of ProcessInstance based on the current record's ID (TargetObjectID in ProcessInstance).

Comment: Then another query of ProcessInstanceSteps based on that ProcessInstance record's ID (ProcessInstanceID in ProcessInstanceStep object). And I'm only getting two PrecessInstanceStep records - one for the Submit (Status = "Started") and then the first Step (Status = "Approved") ; but I don't see a record for the currently Pending step. Is there only a ProcessInstanceStep record created upon approval ? That can't be the case.

Comment: @Zoom_v This sounds like it should be its own question.

Comment: I think you are right Sir.