# Unable to access processnode fields from processinstancestep

Tags: soql, approval-process, standard-objects, approval-step, approval-history

Require to processnode field data from processinstancestep.

While using query-

```
Select StepNodeId from processinstancestep
```

It is returning the values as expected

But while using query-

```
Select StepNode.Name from processinstancestep
```

Facing an error in Salesforce soql

"Didn't understand relationship 'StepNode' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names"

Is this a limitation or am I missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstancestep.htm) there is not a direct relationship StepNode, just the reference as `StepNodeId`

You have to query ProcessNode separately. For what you are trying to do will probably help:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/203081/18194